# Is it better to use numeric or (var)char types for strings of numbers?

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that stores quite a bit of fixed length number strings. 9 digit TINs, credit card numbers, loan numbers, etc.

While it's bad practice to store these as integers, is there any advantages/disadvantages between storing them as `numeric(9,0)` vs `char(9)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type chosen should match how the data is used: if it is a number and might be used for or compared using arithmetic then store it as a number, if it is an identifier and might be corrupted by being dealt with as a number or might need different formats over time then use a string.

For "corrupted by being dealt with as a number", consider that leading zeroes might get taken off which will make the identifier/phone-number/other invalid.

Answer (score -1):

From a storage point, you should use `int` datatype since is smaller than `char(9)` and also can improve index seeks.

And please, don't use `numeric(9,0)` (5 bytes) since you will not perform any math on these fields.

You can find more info here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql

Comment: Not use numeric because they will not perform any math but use int? Doesn't int allow math operations, too?

Comment: yes, you are right! in this particular case i would use int because is smaller than char(9), from a storage point of view :)

Comment: Well, then my question is why not  numeric? From a storage point - or any kind - of view, 5 bytes is less than 9 ;)

Comment: yes, that is i would rather use int :) 4 bytes are better than 5, but you are correct, i think i miss the point with the char(9)